# If Japanese rice wine is called Sake then why is a liquor shop called a Saka-ya?

Tags: translation, word-choice, words

Or is it just my dictionary that made a mistake?

Comment: duplicate of: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3533/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary is correct. Knowing the history of words is not my specialty, but I think I have something to contribute as a fellow learner, anyway...in present day Japanese, you could say **kanji have multiple readings that depend on the context in which they are used**. That is, it depends on the word in which the kanji is included, and/or if other words/grammar constructs are present in a sentence.  (See [this jisho page](http://jisho.org/search/%E9%85%92%20%23kanji) and notice the multiple readings)

In the case of 酒, the kanji is read as "sake". And 酒屋 is read as "saka-ya". Obviously, "sake" is not the same as "saka", so this particular word would be one of those situations to memorize.