# What do we know about vowel variations such as 雨 read as あめ/あま

Tags: history

There are several words which have vowel variations. This seems like it could be a fossilization of morphological processes in an older version of Japanese. How much do we know about these processes? Can we reconstruct a grammatical or phonological explanation for these vowel variations?

```
雨: あめ
雨水: あまみず

月：つき
月読：つくよみ

高：たか
丈：たけ
```

Comment: Is 高・丈 really in the same category as the others?

Comment: Related (and possibly duplicate): [Why is a place that sells さけ a さかや?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3536/542) and [Exceptional compounding forms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2534/542)