# しらゆきひめ 'Snow White'

Tags: phonology, compounds

I am trying to understand [the title of a tale](http://web-ehon.jp/shirayuki.ht/0.html).

- しろ 'white'
- ゆき　'snow'
- ひめ　'princess'
- しらゆきひめ 'Snow White'

If white is しろ, why is 'Snow White' not しろゆきひめ？

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exceptional compounding forms](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2534/exceptional-compounding-forms)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @sawa posted with the link in the comment, sometimes words have exceptional readings when in compound form.  `白（しろ）` is the colour white, but in certain compound words it has the reading `しら`.

Exs:

> しらゆき　→　pure white snow
>   しらさぎ　→　white heron
>   しらが　→　white (grey) hair